# Does == create garbage ? (when comparing a string to a number)

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection

I like to not take care of if a variable is a string or a number when comparing values, so I aways use ==, not ===. But since == converts the two values to the same datatype before comparing, does it create garbage and aggravate those nasty garbage collection short pauses in games ? If it does, does it only when comparing strings to numbers or also when comparing numbers to numbers and strings to strings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `==` can create garbage as it might invoke `.toString()` or `.valueOf()` methods on object when doing type coercions; and those methods might run havoc (they can be user-defined).

But no, `==` will not create garbage when comparing (primitive) strings to (primitive) numbers, all the memory allocated in the process can (and will) be immediately reclaimed after returning the result.

Notice that if you care for garbage-collection speed of your game, you'd rather should care for consistent value types first. That will likely speed up your game more; and when using `===` you can be sure that no garbage is created.

Comment: Let me see if I understood. Let's say I have a=5; and c.b="5", when comparing them with if(a==c.b) or if(a<c.b) no garbage is created because they are primitives, however garbage would be created if I was comparing two arrays. Right ?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't think comparing arrays does create garbage - they're directly stringified. An example for objects would be `"5" == {valueOf: function(){ createLotsOfGarbage(); return 5; }}`

Comment: Ah ok. I never do such an odd thing, creating a function that will "die" rightaway.
I will use === from now on, but actually I hesitate on what to do with the thousands of already existing ==. If they don't create garbage, no problem. If they do (or if they cause deoptimisation by the way) then I should take time to change them. That is why I was asking.

Comment: No, using `==` is no problem. Only using (too many) different types can cause deoptimisations afaik. If you use `==` on operands of the same type, it'll perform just as good as `===`.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator will only create any objects if it actually has do type conversion to an object. If you compare values of the same type, then there is no need to create any values for the comparison.

You should however try to make sure that your data is of the intended type. It's cheaper to convert a value once when you place it in a variable, than have it implicitly converted every time that it's used.

Comment: Then I do not know what to do for example with the highscores I read from localStorage. They come as strings. I will compare them to the score so I should convert them to numbers in order to avoid hidden calls to .valueOf(). But I will also concatenate them with text when drawing the highscores, so if they are numbers there will be hidden calls to .toString(). It's not obvious to guess which is worse.